# How to test a function asking for user input in Python

Tags: python, testing, pytest, stdin

I would like to test the following Python function using pytest:

```
def increase_by_one()
    n = int(input())
    return n + 1
```

How can I write to the stdin/user input request within a function, for testing purposes?

Comment: Where possible, replace calls to `input` with function parameters. It makes your function easier to test, and pushes I/O towards the "edge" of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `input()` function which will return a fix `string`.

```
save_it = input
input = lambda: 'your_simulated_input'
def test():
    s = input() # returns 'your_simulated_input'
    ...
```

Comment: `input` is in the built-in scope. You don't necessarily need to save the reference; it will always be available via `builtins.input`, and you can simply use `del input` to stop shadowing the builtin name.

Comment: thank's for the hint